# grep --include=*.{cpp,cc,cxx} doesn't work if there's only one entry in brackets

Tags: bash, grep, gnu

I used `grep -F -e "function1" --include=*.{cpp,c} . -r -n` to find use of `function1` but then realized I could speed it up so I removed `c` from `--include` but then it doesn't work.

Why?

This doesn't work ->`grep -F -e "function1" --include=*.{cpp} . -r -n`

It'll run but won't return anything. If I add a second item i.e. `--include=*.{cpp,dsafjlsadfsaldf}` then it works.

Comment: This is a shell functionality, not specific to `grep`.  Since you already tagged [gnu], I added [bash].

Comment: `*.{cpp,c}` gets expanded to `*.cpp *.c` whereas `*.{cpp}` is still `*.{cpp}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are relying on the shell's "brace expansion" feature.  To quote the Bash manual,

> A correctly-formed brace expansion must contain unquoted opening and closing braces, ***and at least one unquoted comma*** or a valid sequence expression.

Without any commas, the text is not eligible for brace expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Observe:

```
$ echo {a,b}
a b
$ echo {a}
{a}
```

In other words, *brace expansion* only works if there are two more elements within the braces.  If you have only one element, don't use braces.

Again, but addressing the specific options you are using:

```
$ echo  --include=*.{cpp,c} 
--include=*.cpp --include=*.c
$ echo  --include=*.{cpp} 
--include=*.{cpp}
```

To get the latter to work correctly, remove braces:

```
$ echo  --include=*.cpp
--include=*.cpp
```